# AWS ACL not blocking IP address

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, vpc

I have a couple of hosts running on Elasticbeanstalk in AWS. I have been getting over 250 requests a minutes on / from some other machines who's DNS is on route 53, and based on their IP's are on AWS as well. I added two inbound rules(50,55) to block DENY ALL on those IPS and my VPC associated with my Elastic-loadbalancer and Elasticbeanstalk subnets. The traffic is still getting through. Any ideas?

Comment: Blocking IPs via VPC Network ACLs definitely works - as long as your DENY rules are before the 0.0.0.0 ALLOW rule, it should be fine. Can you show your config? Also, make sure you're looking at the remote IP via your ELB access logs - if you look at the logs on your web servers, it may be showing the IP of your ELB rather than the true remote IP.

Comment: I am using the IP from an nslookup of the host, and compared with my logs on the EB instance. Let me check the LB logs to be safe. I changed the actual IP to 1.2.3.4 in both instances.                             `50
ALL Traffic
ALL
ALL
1.2.3.4/32
DENY
55
ALL Traffic
ALL
ALL
1.2.3.4/32
DENY
100
ALL Traffic
ALL
ALL
0.0.0.0/0
ALLOW
*
ALL Traffic
ALL
ALL
0.0.0.0/0
DENY`

Comment: Your rules look fine, so all I can think of is that the remote IP isn't correct or something more fundamental is misconfigured (such as the Network ACL not being associated with the right subnet or something.) Try verifying that your Network ACL rules are working by blocking an IP that you know (for instance, your phone's IP when it is not on wifi.)

Answer (score 3):

Appreciate this is an old question, but sharing my experience from today when solving (I think) the same problem -

If you have a reverse proxy service (eg. Cloudflare) sat between your users and your infrastructure, the IP that presents to the AWS Network ACL will be Cloudflare's IP, not the IP you are attempting to block and therefore the rule won't work.

Testing with my own IP, I turned off the reverse proxy aspect of the setup on Cloudflare, and the Network ACL rules kicked in immediately.